# Sublime Text 2 Comment/Doc Block

Tags: phpdoc, sublimetext

Recently, I decided to try out Sublime Text 2 as a TextMate alternative (which it is). I'm absolutely loving it but the only issue that bugs me is that it doesn't continue the PHP Comment/Doc Block upon pressing "Enter".

It just adds new blank lines instead of lines starting with "* " as seen here http://cl.ly/AFcP/o

Is there a solution to this? I tried doing a key binding for it but it was just too complicated for me, especially because I'm not too experienced with the editor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Link in Question is broken

Answer (score 61, accepted):

And now an even better solution has become available:

https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs

It is called DocBlockr, and it has PHPDoc support. It automatically adds the doc block based on the function parameters. Nice...

Answer (score 24):

Just had the same problem and wrote a little snippet. Since it is a keybinding it has to be stored in a *.sublime-keymap* File. If you're on a Mac just goto *Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Key Bindings - User* or similar on some other OS.

Here is my Code:

```
[
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n * "}, "context": [
    {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
    {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\/\\*\\*$", "match_all": true}
]},
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n* "}, "context": [
    //{"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
    {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[\t ]*\\*[^\\/]", "match_all": true}
]}
]
```

Comment: O_o ... totally amazed that you can achieve something like that just by modifying "key-bindings"! sublime text 2 FTW

Comment: @Handfeger Any ideas how we can close the DocBlock, if the last line is empty and we press `enter` again?

Comment: I think DocBlockr adds this feature as well. Its much more advanced than my solution

Comment: Now you can use **PHPDoc** Package [from github](https://github.com/SublimeText/PhpDoc). [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) make it most easily (after install.. **Preferences->Package Control**.. choose **Install Package**.. type **PHPDoc**). By default autocomplete is **Alt+/**