# Big comments with Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext

I would like to make comments like this in Sublime Text 2:

```
/********************
* This is a comment *
********************/
```

Is there an easy way to make those automatically?

Also, where can I find good documentation about such stuff. I love Sublime, but I feel it's poorly documented!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could create a snippet for doing this.

Go to `Tools` -> `New Snippet` and a new file is opened. Paste this in it:

```
<snippet>
<content>
<![CDATA[

/********************
* $0 *
********************/

]]>

</content>
<tabTrigger>bigcom</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Save this in your `Packages\User`-Folder (which should be set automatically when saving).
Now you can just type `bigcom` (as defined in the `<tabTrigger>` - element) and hit `tab`. The comment will appear and the cursor is set at the position, where `$0` is set in the snippet.

Additionaly, you could add a `scope` - element inside the `<snippet>`-block, so this snippet will only work in a specific syntax scope, for example:

```
<scope>source.python</scope>
```

Unfurtonately, I don't know how you could add the `*`-character on both sides of the line you are writing in automatically, when you jump into a new line, so I don't know if this fits your needs. You would have to add those manually. Still I hope this helps in some way.

**Edit:**
Found something for this in another question on stackoverflow. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478151/sublime-text-2-comment-doc-block). When doing this, at least the `*` character on the beginning of the new line is added. I'll have a look if I can get it to add the character at the end of the line too.

---

When it comes to the documentation, I agree, there's not really a lot out there. Of course there is the official documentation: [Sublime Doc](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/) and of course the forum: [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) (which is a good resource to some point, not like the poorly filled Doc). On the other hand I always recommend reading the post on [net.tutsplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/), which is a nice starting point.

I pretty much stumbled over the most interesting parts that come with the standard installation while browsing trough the `Global Settings` and `Key Bindings`-Files, which you can open over the `Preferences` - Menu

Comment: How to make it work differently in diffent file types. like css, scss, html ect

Answer (score 16):

*Warning, self plug.*

The [DocBlockr plugin](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs) can automatically 'decorate' a comment for you. Right now it only works on inline comments, but it gets the job done. The shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd>

```
// foo bar baz
```

Becomes

```
/////////////////
// foo bar baz //
/////////////////
```

And it works on consecutive comments too:

```
// foo
// bar baz quux
```

Becomes

```
//////////////////
// foo          //
// bar baz quux //
//////////////////
```

Comment: this plugin now supports JsDoc block comments btw

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using the DocBlockr plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use this handy sublime plugin https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Comment-Snippets