# Syntax-Specific Block Comments for Latex in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, comments, latex, sublimetext2, code-snippets

Recently, I came across a post with an excellent script to continue a block comment in sublime text for CSS, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478151/sublime-text-2-comment-doc-block/7552608#7552608). And adding it to an environment-specific keybindings file works like a charm. However when I try to change it for use with latex comments, (i.e. substituting the * for %) it does not work.

Original Code:

```
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n * "}, 
"context": 
    [
        {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
        "operand": "\\/\\*\\*$", "match_all": true}
    ]
},
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n* "}, 
"context": 
    [
        //{"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
        "operand": "^[\t ]*\\*[^\\/]", "match_all": true}
    ]
},
```

My Code:

```
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n % "}, 
"context": 
    [
        {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
        "operand": "\\/\\%\\%$", "match_all": true}
    ]
},

{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n % "}, 
"context": 
    [
        //{"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
        "operand": "^[\t ]%\\%[^\\/]", "match_all": true}
    ]
},
```

Comment: Define `does not work`. Also note that `*` are quantifiers which means `match the preceding token zero or more times`. It's also quite vague, I mean what is this script supposed to do. Can you provide some input of both cases ?

Comment: It is supposed to add % to each new line within a block comment section, that is, it checks to see if there are comment characters (* in css, % in latex). By does not work, I mean it adds nothing. However the first one adds the *.

Comment: What's a comment in latex ? Is it `/% this is a comment %/` ?

Comment: You changed one `*`, too many: `^[\t ]*\\%[^\\/]`, or just `^[\t ]*%[^\\/]` (because, as HamZa said, the first `*` is a quantifier). However, LaTeX has no such thing as a block comment, does it (unless you define it yourself). Currently the snippet still expects a block comment to start with `/%%`, which wouldn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so there were two major flaws with what I was trying to do. Firstly, I did indeed make a mistake with the regex and replaced too many *s. and secondly, the original code was for CSS which has block comments styled

```
/*
*
*
*/
```

Whereas the style of latex block comment that I was going for (which is not built-in) was a block with a header and a footer defining the limits of the comment and maintaining the text contained within this would also be commented, e.g.:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%% Comment Section Start %%%%%%%%%%%%
   %%%  Comments here
%%%%%%%%%%%% Comment Section Ends  %%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The following can do this for both latex and it can be modified to do the equivalent with R so that comments can be added quickly and consistently. I use it together with a snippet that adds the header and the footer sections.

```
//
{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n%%%\t"}, 
"context": 
    [
        {"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
         "operand": "\t*%%%.*$", "match_all": true}
    ]},

{"keys": ["enter"], "command": "insert", "args" : {"characters": "\n%%%\t"}, 
"context": 
    [
        //{"key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true},
        {"key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", 
          "operand": "\t*%%%", "match_all": true}
    ]},
```

Thanks for the helpful comments!!